# Making a HANDLE RAII-compliant using shared_ptr with a custom deleter

Tags: c++, winapi, raii

I've recently posted a general question about RAII at [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556168/making-a-non-object-resource-raii-compliant).
However, I still have some implementation issues with my HANDLE example.

A `HANDLE` is typedeffed to `void *` in `windows.h`. Therefore, the correct `shared_ptr` definition needs to be

```
std::tr1::shared_ptr<void> myHandle (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, CloseHandle);
```

**Example 1** `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`: returns `HANDLE` and works.

```
const std::tr1::shared_ptr<void> h
    (CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL), CloseHandle);
```

As I use `void` in the definition (what is the correct way?) problems go on, when I try to call some more winapi commands with this pointer. They functionally work, but are ugly and I am sure that there has to be a better solution.

In the following examples, `h` is a pointer which was created via the definition at the top.

**Example 2** `OpenProcessToken`: last argument is a `PHANDLE`. medium ugly with the cast.

```
OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY,
    (PHANDLE)&h);
```

**Example 3** `Process32First`: first argument is a `HANDLE`. REALLY ugly.

```
Process32First(*((PHANDLE)&h), &pEntry);
```

**Example 4** simple comparison with a constant `HANDLE`. REALLY ugly.

```
if (*((PHANDLE)&h) == INVALID_HANDLE) { /* do something */ }
```

What is the correct way to create a proper shared_ptr for a HANDLE?

Comment: Not a complete answer, but one can slightly reduce "ugliness" of using `void` type by using `std::remove_pointer<HANDLE>::type` from `type_traits` instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Example 1 is OK

Example 2 is wrong. By blindly casting to PHANDLE, the shared_ptr logic is bypassed. It should be something like this instead:

```
HANDLE h;
OpenProcessToken(...., &h);
shared_ptr<void> safe_h(h, &::CloseHandle);
```

or, to assign to a pre-exising shared_ptr:

```
shared_ptr<void> safe_h = ....
{
  HANDLE h;
  OpenProcessToken(...., &h);
  safe_h.reset(h, &::CloseHandle);
}//For extra safety, limit visibility of the naked handle
```

or, create your own, safe, version of OpenProcessToken that returns a shared handle instead of taking a PHANDLE:

```
// Using SharedHandle defined at the end of this post
SharedHandle OpenProcess(....)
{
    HANDLE h = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    ::OpenProcessToken(...., &h);
    return SharedHandle(h);
}
```

Example 3: No need to take these detours. This should be ok:

```
Process32First(h.get(), ...);
```

Example 4: Again, no detour:

```
if (h.get() == INVALID_HANDLE){...}
```

To make things nicer, you could typedef something like:

```
typedef shared_ptr<void> SharedHandle;
```

or better yet, if all handles are to be closed with CloseHandle(), create a SharedHandle class wrapping a shared_ptr and automatically providing the right deleter:

```
// Warning: Not tested. For illustration purposes only
class SharedHandle
{
public:
  explicit SharedHandle(HANDLE h) : m_Handle(h, &::CloseHandle){};
  HANDLE get()const{return m_Handle.get();}

  //Expose other shared_ptr-like methods as needed
  //...

private:
  shared_ptr<void> m_Handle;
};
```

Comment: is there some possibility to delete the unsafe `HANDLE` after converting it to a safe one in your first example 2 code snippet?

Comment: You could create a function wrapping OpenProcessHandle() (I added this to the post) or do the same thing than in the second snippet, with shared_h initialized to INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE

Answer (score 3):

Don't bother with shared_ptr for that, use ATL::CHandle.

Here is why:

- When you see `CHandle` you know that it's a RAII wrapper for a handle.
- When you see `shared_ptr<void>` you don't know what it is.
- `CHandle` doesn't make an ownership shared (however in some cases you may want a shared ownership).
- `CHandle` is a standard for a windows development stack.
- `CHandle` is more compact than `shared_ptr<void>` with custom deleter (less typing/reading).

Comment: Can you expand on that? The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5fc6ft2t.aspx) doesn't say much, but it looks more like a unique_ptr, I don't see how CHandle facilitates sharing.

Comment: @phant0m CHandle doesn't provide a shared ownership.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [boost 2: shared_ptr wraps resource handles](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/stl/boostsp_handleref.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Here is my alternative, which is quite nice except you need to dereference always after `.get()` and requires a functor or lambda:

```
template<typename HandleType, typename Deleter>
std::shared_ptr<HandleType> make_shared_handle(HandleType _handle, Deleter _dx)
{
    return std::shared_ptr<HandleType>(new HandleType(_handle), _dx);
}
```

then:

```
auto closeHandleDeleter = [](HANDLE* h) {
    ::CloseHandle(*h);
    delete h;
};
std::shared_ptr<HANDLE> sp = make_shared_handle(a_HANDLE, closeHandleDeleter);
f_that_takes_handle(*sp.get());
```

what I like most about this is there is no extra work to have access to this:

```
std::weak_ptr<HANDLE> wp = sp; // Yes. This could make sense in some designs.
```

and of course, the helper function works with any handle type of the likes.